# powershell copy-item public desktop access denied

Tags: powershell, copy

Below is the powershell script I am running, I am a local administrator on the workstations in the PClist.txt and I have the modify right on the share location. When I run it I get the following error:

copy-item : Access to the path '\computer_name\C$\Users\Public\Desktop\Program.exe' is denied.
At line:5 char:35
+ ...  | foreach {copy-item -path $sourcefile -destination \$_\C$\$destina ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\share_name\program.exe:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Any help to resolve this issue would be great... I do believe the issue is because the public desktop is a hidden folder thus the access_denied but I do not know how to bypass it.

```
$computers = "C:\temp\PClist.txt"
$sourcefile = "\\share_name\Program.exe"
$destination = "Users\Public\Desktop"

get-content $computers | foreach {copy-item -path $sourcefile -destination \\$_\C$\$destination}
```

Comment: What computer is the script running on? Is it a computer that you are logged directly onto or another computer through RDP or some other remote control option?

Comment: Also, according to the error you posted the URL is invalid anyway since it starts with one \ not two.

Comment: I am running it from my PC, I am using my pc as a test. I am a full admin on my PC. I believe the issue is that by design the public desktop is hidden thus the access denied, I do not know how to bypass this.

Comment: When I use a folder that is not hidden I do not get any errors and the script works

Comment: Does it work with the `-Force` parameter?

Comment: I have tried adding the -force switch at the end of the $destination piece but it still errors out.

Comment: Please post the code that you ran with `-Force` in your question.

Comment: get-content $computers | foreach {copy-item -path $sourcefile -destination \\$_\C$\$destination -force}

Comment: Beats me then. I've never seen that issue. I guess you could remove the Hidden attribute, copy the file, then reapply the Hidden attribute.

Comment: I would also suggest buidling the destination path separately then Write-Host that path to make sure it is building correctly.

Comment: I will use a gpo to do this